# Hi what i am doing wrong with this query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to select the income amount from income table, update the total income and subtract the income from the total income. Then delete the row.

```
public function delete($id)
{ 
    $this->db->get('income');
    $this->db->select('income_amount');
    $this->db->query('update total_income set amount=amount-'.$this->db->select('income_amount'));

    $this->db->where('income_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('income');    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand u r question ..?

Comment: Is this only for the selected row, with `income_id = $id`? What is the current behavior and what is expected?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, you want to do the following :

1. Select `income_amount` from the `income` table :

   ```
   $this->db->select('income_amount');
   $query = $this->db->get('income');
   $row = $query->row();

   if (isset($row)) {
       $income_amount = $row->income_amount;
   }
   ```
2. Update the `total_income` table by substracting `$income_amount` from **all** the `amount` values of the table :

   ```
   $this->db->set('amount', 'amount-'.$income_amount);
   $this->db->update('total_income');
   ```
3. Delete the row identified by `$id` from the `income` table :

   ```
   $this->db->delete('income', array('income_id' => $id));
   ```